# How do i make this query with two conditions?

Tags: sql, subquery

database structure

```
    Professor
        prof_id number
        name string
        salary number
        building string
    Course
        name string
        prof_id number
        room_number number
        start_time number
        end_time number
    Room
        room_number number
        capacity number
        building string
```

Professors with at least 1 math course:

```
select distinct Professor.name, count(Course.name)  AS numberOfMathCourses
from Course
LEFT JOIN Room
ON Course.Room_id = Room.Room.id
INNER JOIN Professor
ON Professor.id = Course.id
where Course.name = 'math' 
group by Professor.name
having numberOfMathCourses > 0
```

Professors with less than 3 courses :

```
select distinct Professor.name, count(Course.name)  AS numberOfCourses
from Course
LEFT JOIN Room
ON Course.Room_id = Room.Room.id
INNER JOIN Professor
ON Professor.id = Course.id
group by Professor.name
having numberOfCourses < 3
```

how would do I create a Query that has both of these conditions ? **more than one math course** course and **less than 3 courses**.

I tried sub-queries but I wasn't able to make it work. I will try to look into it more. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from Professor p
where 
    (select count(*) from Course c where p.prof_id = c.prof_id and c.name = 'math') > 0
    and (select count(*) from Course c where p.prof_id = c.prof_id) < 3
```